# duplicate guava.jar in classpath

Tags: java, hbase, apache-storm

I use storm-0.10 to put data to hbase-1.0.1, and storm use guava-12.0 which hbase use guava-18.0, both are load into classpath, it leads to my job fail.

How to ensure storm and hbase use the correct version jar?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:434) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:60) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1122) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1109) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1261) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1125) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:369) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:320) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:206) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.flush(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:183) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1513) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:1107) ~[hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.6.0.jar:?]
at com.lujinhong.demo.storm.kinit.stormkinitdemo.HBaseHelper.put(HBaseHelper.java:182) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.lujinhong.demo.storm.kinit.stormkinitdemo.HBaseHelper.put(HBaseHelper.java:175) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.lujinhong.demo.storm.kinit.stormkinitdemo.PrepaidFunction.execute(PrepaidFunction.java:79) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at storm.trident.planner.processor.EachProcessor.execute(EachProcessor.java:65) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at storm.trident.planner.SubtopologyBolt$InitialReceiver.receive(SubtopologyBolt.java:206) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at storm.trident.planner.SubtopologyBolt.execute(SubtopologyBolt.java:146) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.execute(TridentBoltExecutor.java:370) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$tuple_action_fn__5696.invoke(executor.clj:690) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5615.invoke(executor.clj:436) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__5189.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707$fn__5758.invoke(executor.clj:819) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you using maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

For gradle:

```
compile("sample.ProjectA:staorm:1.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava' module: 'guava'
}
```

Comment: I use both storm & hbase in my topology, so guava-12.0 should in cp for hbase, and guava-18.0 should in cp for storm. Otherwise, storm or hbase doe not work right.

Comment: I think, more correct way is simply update hbase to last version(1.2.1)

Comment: I fix this by putting both guava-12.0.jar & guava-18.0.jar into storm/lib, But I don’t think it is a good solution.
Any why both jar in classpath won’t cause confliction?